# How to get number of points of a polydata from sourceproxy?

Tags: python, paraview

I would like to check the number of points of the active source from python shell, without Fetching the object. 
How can I access this information, similarly to PointData[:] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

> source.GetDataInformation().GetNumberOfPoints()

source.GetDataInformation() returns an [vtkPVDataInformation](http://www.paraview.org/ParaView3/Doc/Nightly/www/cxx-doc/classvtkPVDataInformation.html) object with other useful methods.

Remember that the source must have been "executed" to get valid information. i.e. if needed, call source.UpdatePipeline() before calling GetDataInformation().